# JSP new dialog page best practice

Tags: html, jsp

I'm working on an existing page. And there's a button on the page. It's like:

```
<html>
    <script src="..."></script>
    ...
    <div><input>...</input></div>
</html>
```

After click the button, a pop up dialog page(it's a fully functional page, not just displaying some messages) will show. It's like:

```
<html>
    <script src="..."></script>
    ...
    <div><input>...</input></div>

    <div>
        <iframe>
            <html>
                <script src="..."></script>
                <form>
                ...
                </form>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</html>
```

In the new page, I have to load all the necessary script again which takes a lot of time.

My question is:

1. I'm doubtful about this kind of implementation, can someone comment on this?
2. what's the best practice for this kind of scenario(open a new dialog page)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "popup dialog page"? If it's a new page, it needs its own JS. If it's a "dialog box" in the sense most people use the term, it's the same page and doesn't. Either way, if your server is set up properly, the JS should be cached by the browser anyway.

Comment: "popup dialog page" means it's a dialog basically. And inside the dialog it's a complete page containing a form. You can refresh/change/submit the dialog page.

Comment: Is it a new browser window or is it something showing up inside a DOM element? If the latter, does it need to *also* work standalone, i.e., as an isolated page in a new window?